# how check whether style has appended or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is my code,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.class1 {
  color:red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to check whether class1 has used or appended in style tag in jquery? how it's possible..

Comment: You want to check if the class exists?

Comment: What about checkiing count of elements which have this class?

Comment: Is your question means:
Is the style tag contains class 'class1', or
Is class 'class1' has applied to any html element??
Please clarify your question.

Comment: i need to check whether class1 style has exits or not

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you want to find if the style is provided within the style tag. Just get all the style tags - and see if the class is within the tags

```
var found_class = false;
$('style').each(function() {
   if ($(this).html().indexOf('.class1') > -1) {
      found_class = true;
      return false;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be easily done with jQuery, but here's a 'vanilla' JavaScript way to do it...

Stylesheets have a `cssRules` property that contains a list of its rules, ordered by the index in which they appear in the stylesheet. So basically, you can 'loop' through the rules and try to find one that matches your search.

**The function:**

```
function ruleExists(sheetId, selector) {
    var styleSheet = document.getElementById(sheetId);
    if(!styleSheet || styleSheet.tagName !== 'STYLE') return false;
    styleSheet = styleSheet.sheet.cssRules;
    for (var i = styleSheet.length; i--;) {
        if(styleSheet[i].selectorText === selector) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

So just add an `id` to your stylesheet (I find it more convenient than using document.styleSheets, but you can modify the function to use that instead), and pass the stylesheet's id and desired rule selector to the function. (Of course, if you are using ids, this will only work for inline stylesheets). Here's an example:

**Your stylesheet:**

```
<style type="text/css" id="styleShizz">
    .class1 {
        color: red;
    }
</style>
```

**Your JavaScript:**

```
ruleExists('styleShizz', '.class1'); // true
ruleExists('styleShizz', '.class2'); // false
```

---

**Here's an example JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/kfubnwx2/5/

Answer (score 0):

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/cahake/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

you can use have **.hasClass()** to inspect it in jquery. The method return **true** or **false** about whether contain class what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if ($(".class1")[0]){
    //exists
} else {
    // Do something if class does not exist
}
```